# MySql docker container permission issue

Tags: mysql, docker

After our IT department increased the server's RAM memory MySql docker container stopped working all of the sudden.
The initial error was:

```
2021-10-05 07:49:44+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.22-1debian10 started.
2021-10-05 07:49:44+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2021-10-05 07:49:44+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.22-1debian10 started.
2021-10-05 07:49:44+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2021-10-05T07:49:44.695485Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25) initializing of server in progress as process 44
2021-10-05T07:49:44.700805Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-10-05T07:49:44.709596Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012576] [InnoDB] Unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
2021-10-05T07:49:44.709749Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012929] [InnoDB] InnoDB Database creation was aborted with error Generic error. You may need to delete the ibdata1 file before trying to start up again.
2021-10-05T07:49:44.710086Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2021-10-05T07:49:44.710162Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2021-10-05T07:49:44.710272Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

So I've mapped the docker /tmp directory to the host's /tmp dir using the docker-compose `volumes` tag, which solved this issue but now I have another issue that I cannot solve, I literally can't find anything about this issue that works.
I suspect the IT person changed something in the system that cause this issue, but I can't find what.

```
2021-10-05 12:32:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.22-1debian10 started.
2021-10-05 12:32:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2021-10-05 12:32:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.22-1debian10 started.
2021-10-05T12:32:08.648765Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25) starting as process 1
2021-10-05T12:32:08.656676Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-10-05T12:32:08.829920Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-10-05T12:32:08.920421Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011300] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Setup of socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' failed, can't create lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock.lock'
2021-10-05T12:32:08.921019Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2021-10-05T12:32:09.027024Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-10-05T12:32:09.027478Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-10-05T12:32:09.030560Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010273] [Server] Could not create unix socket lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.lock.
2021-10-05T12:32:09.030972Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010268] [Server] Unable to setup unix socket lock file.
2021-10-05T12:32:09.031807Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

Any kind of help would be appriciated.

Comment: Your container need to have permission to write to `/var/run/mysqld/`, have you mounted that directory inside container to the host volume too? Can you share the permission of that directory?

Comment: @TruongHua It worked before even without mounting the directory. But yes I have mounted it and nothing happened.May I add that I have another elasticsearch docker container that has the same permission error for some reason.

Comment: Can you share your `docker run` command or your docker-compose file. If it's your self-built docker image, please share the Dockerfile too.